# Making a beginner C program to read and sort student according to ages

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, data-structures

Code :

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    typedef struct person {
        int age ;
        char name[40];
    }person;

    void perm ( person * A , person * B ){
        person temp ;
        temp = *A ;
        *A = *B ;
        *B = temp ;
    }

    void main () {
        person classroom[6];
        int i , j ;
        // reading students name and ages
        for ( i=0 ; i<6 ; i++ ){
            printf("Enter name :");
            fgets (classroom[i].name, 40, stdin);
            printf("Enter age : ");
            scanf("%d",&classroom[i].age);
        }
        // sorting them
        for ( i=0 ; i<6 ; i++ ){
            for ( j=0 ; j<6-i ; j++ ){
                if ( classroom[j].age > classroom[j+1].age ){
                    perm (&classroom[j],&classroom[j+1]);
                }
            }
        }
        // printing them sorted
        printf("\n After sorting accoring to ages :");
        for ( i=0 ; i<6 ; i++ ){
            printf(" %s \n",classroom[i].name[40]);
        }
        // finished
        getchar();
        getchar();

    }
```

The program is supposed to :

1. Define student type " person " .
2. Define a two persons swap procedure " void perm ( person * A , person * B ) ; " .
3. Declaring an array of persons named " classroom " .
4. Filling the array names and ages .
5. Sorting using a bubble sort algorithm .
6. Showing the array after sorting .

Comment: And your question supposed to be ...?

Comment: You don't seem to be asking a question. Please make it something specific.

Comment: are we supposed to write your homework for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick check and I noticed at least 3 major errors in that code:

1) when you look for the student name, you will be in trouble as the '\n' is not handled properly in the scanf, to handle that properly you need to consume '\n', for example you can add getc() straight after the scanf as I do in the following snippet:

```
 for ( i=0 ; i<6 ; i++ ){
        printf("Enter name :");
        fgets (classroom[i].name, 40, stdin);
        printf("Enter age : ");
        scanf("%d",&classroom[i].age);
       /* Add this one will catch the \n for you making the code working better */
        getc(stdin); /* <<<<< ADD THIS LINE */ 
}
```

2) There is a buffer overflow here:

```
 for ( j=0 ; j<6-i ; j++ ){
            if ( classroom[j].age > classroom[j+1].age ){
                perm (&classroom[j],&classroom[j+1]);
            }
   }
```

when i=0, j=5 => classroom[j+1]==>classroom[6] and index 6 it's outside the boundaries. you need to set your loop to 5 at maximum

```
for ( j=0 ; j<5-i ; j++ ){
     if ( classroom[j].age > classroom[j+1].age ){
         perm (&classroom[j],&classroom[j+1]);
     }
}
```

3) When you print the result you point beyond the end of the string. Moreover you don't point to a string but you try to get the first character outside the space you reserved for the name because you missed the symbol '&', instead of:

```
printf(" %s \n",classroom[i].name[40]);
```

You must use the following:

```
printf(" %s \n", &classroom[i].name[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this question should be corrected into a proper question so that it may turn out to be an appropriate Stack Overflow entry. With that piece of code you'd have four questions:

> **1 -** Why am I being prompted to enter the `Age` of the 2nd (and subsequent) student(s) without having entered his/her `Name` first?
>   **2 -** Why am I experiencing Access Violation (or Segmentation Fault, whatever) with this code?
>   **3 -** Why am I still experiencing Access Violation?
>   **4 -** Why are names being displayed with double line-breaks?

**For the first question,** `stdin` is a buffered input. I might be missing the true definition of what *buffered* means, but what you and I should know here is that when you type:

```
20*pressTheEnterKey*
```

You push the following inside the `stdin` buffer:

```
'2' '0' '\n'
```

The first two characters are obtained and used by the `scanf` you had called, since they are valuable for the `%d` type specifier. The new line character `\n` is left, however.

With the next call of the `fgets`, you ask for a stream of characters from `stdin` until you hit a new line character, which has already been provided. `fgets` stores the new line inside the `classroom[i].name` and moves on.

You wouldn't want that, right?

To prevent that, you'll have to discard that `\n`, and to do that you have two options:

- `fflush( stdin );` call, I personally use this because it works for me, [but it might not be working all the time according to this](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html), so...
- `while( getchar( ) != '\n' );` should also discard every character left inside the buffer until the new line character, including the new line character

**Now for the second question;** within the nested `for` loop, you are trying to access the memory location `classroom[6].age` for `i == 0` and `j == 5`. That location is out of the limits that `person classroom[6];` covers: from `classroom[0]` to `classroom[5]`.

Fixing that is easy, just change the inner `for` condition to be:

```
for ( ... ; j < 5 - i ; ... ) { ... }
```

**For your third question;** this time you are trying to access the memory location `classroom[i].name[40]` which is out of bounds for any `i`. Besides, even if it wasn't, `classroom[i].name[n]` would point to a character for every `n: 0 <= n <= 39`, and that is not how you print out a string (an array of characters) `%s` with `printf`.

You print strings out by using the address of the very first character on a string (array of characters). In this case, that would be the address of `classroom[i].name[0]`, which could be written in the following two ways:

- `&classroom[i].name[0]` or
- `classroom[i].name`, better isn't it?

**Now, the last question...** Remember what I had said for `fgets` above?

> *`fgets` stores the new line inside the `classroom[i].name` and moves on.*

`fgets` stores the characters, usually until hits a new line character, and including the new line character. That is why you get double line-breaks. Easy way to get rid of this is to take out the `\n` in your last `printf`. I personally would rather use `scanf_s` or store characters character-by-character with `getchar` and then discard the trash buffered input with `fflush`, but whatever.

This is what you'll get if you don't explicitly ask something specific, a wall of text.